# Dropdown used on multiple pages, should I componentize it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I got this dropdown that will be utilized on some pages and I am concerning if I should componentize it and include it on each page or if I call the dropdown service on each service that is needed. I building a spring mvc with thymeleaf

Comment: if you have the same dropdown (with the same items) on several pages, then perhaps you can place it in a thymeleaf fragment and include that fragment wherever needed. This way, if you ever need to change that dropdown you can do it in one, instead of, several places.

Comment: it make sense but how could I pass the data to the fragment without having to call the dropdown service on each controller page? is it possible?

Comment: does your dropdown contain dynamic data, which change between different pages? If so, than you'll obviously have to call the dropdown service for every page.

Comment: no it doesnt it is the same data

Comment: if your data doesn't change, then perhaps you can store them in a session variable (javax.servlet.http.HttpSession), which can then be referenced from thymeleaf (e.g ${session.dropdownList} )

Comment: oh that might work, thanks...any idea on how I could refresh the data? cause it is the same data for all pages but it is dynamic meaning that I could add new entries for the dropdown

Comment: no shortcuts here, you will have to call the dropdown service any time your data have changed.  So just update the session any time your data have changed.

Comment: that data could be updated by other app/process, is there any place where I could hook my code to update the session?

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911341/spring-getting-notified-on-db-changes. I haven't used any of these options myself

Comment: I was looking for something on the Spring lifecycle, the notification from db might work but it kinda defeat the purpose of easy maintainability of the dropdown I think I go with the code duplication approach since my app is not large enough for this complexity. Thanks for your inputs @dsp_user

Comment: @dsp_user post your approach as an answer so we can help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case when you have a dropdown, or any other html element for that matter, that needs to appear on several pages, it makes sense to place that element(s) inside a thymeleaf fragment so as to avoid code duplication. Not only do you avoid code duplication, but your code will become easier to maintain as well (because there's less code to maintain).

```
<div  th:fragment="dropdownFragment">
....
<select> 
<th:block th:each="item : ${dropdownItems}">
  <option th:value="${item}" th:text="${item}"></option>
</th:block>
</select>
</div>
```

In order to reduce the number of trips to the database, we should cache our data. Possibly the easiest way to do this is to make use of the built in HttpSession object (especially when our data is relatively small).The code might look something like

```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  //code to retrive data from the db
  session.setAttribute("dropdownItems", dropdownItems);
```

The session object can be referenced in thymeleaf as `#{session.some_object}` but this has been deprecated since Thymeleaf 3.1. For this reason, it's best to copy the session attribute into a Model (or ModelAndView) object, which can then be referenced as `${modelObject}`.

```
@GetMapping("/getItems")
public ModelAndView getDropdownItems(HttpSession session )
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
  mv.setViewName("someView");
 //this assumes that you already have a session with dropdownItemsattribute
  mv.addObject("dropdownItems", session.getAttribute("dropddownItems"));
  return mv;
 }
```

Hope this helps.